# angular directive won't receive parameters when not clearing browser cache

Tags: angularjs, caching

The more I try, the more I see I know nothing.

I'm experiencing a very odd issue with an angular 1.x application. I have an index.html that loads an angular directive, passing some parameters to it.

I'm forced to clear the cache everytime I want to run index.html or the directive won't receive any parameters. If I do not clear the cache, parameters aren't passed to the directive. Directive receives nothing.

I wonder what kind of configuration conflict is causing the parameters not to be passed to the directive.

Index.html:

```
        <super-combo-directive-e-controller
                    type='lens'
                    label-displacement='0px'
                    icon-top-displacement='3px'
                    icon-right-displacement='-1px'
                    main-label='Business Transaction'
                    text-box-width="350px"
                    combo-width="530px"
                    lupa-width="80%"
                    caller="myCaller"
                    called="myCalled"
                    col-a-name="Identification Code"
                    col-b-name="Identification Description" 
                    http-params='"idCode":"0", "IdName":"0"'
                    http-returned=''
                    url="/v1/myUrl"
                    label-class = "col-md-6"
                    component-class = "col-md-6"
                    tabindex='4'>
         </super-combo-directive-e-controller>
```

Directive:

```
function superComboDirectiveEController() {
    var directive = {
        restrict : 'E',
        templateUrl : "/myTemplate",

        scope : {
            memory: '@',
            sendSelectedTo: '@',
            receiveSelectedFrom: '@',
            itemsPerPage : '@',
            labelDisplacement : '@',
            afterBoxDisplacement : '@',
            iconRightDisplacement : '@',
            iconTopDisplacement : '@',
            type : '@',
            mainLabel : '@',
            cache : '@',
            colALabel : '@',
            colBLabel : '@',
            colAVisible : '@',
            colBVisible : '@',
            textBoxWidth : '@',
            comboWidth : '@',
            lupaWidth : '@',
            caller : '@',
            called : '@',
            mandat : '@',
            colAName : '@',
            colBName : '@',
            httpParams : '@',
            httpReturned : '@',
            url : '@',
            nextFieldClass : '@',
            styleLabel : '@',
            styleText : '@',
            labelClass : '@',
            componentClass : '@',
            classText : '@',
            tabindex : '@'
        },
        controller : PseudoComboController,
        controllerAs : 'c1'
    };
    return directive;
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Are you using angular routing for your page?

Comment: also, your directive... all the scoped vars, why???

Comment: Hi, yes I'm using angular routing. Is it a problem? I'm using ngroute to navigate between html's. My problem is any given html invoking an angular directive and not being able to pass parameters.

Comment: Do you mean why I`m using scoped variables in the directive? I just don't know how to do it differently.

Comment: @user2568276 then you need a cache buster,  Please check the GIST for implementing cache busting [here](https://gist.github.com/ecowden/4637806), can you try this code and see if the problem persists?

Comment: @user2568276 Please use the wallter code in comments in the link [here](https://gist.github.com/ecowden/4637806), this is the approach to take so that you will get the latest page and not the cached one! If you can try other methods you can find on the internet!

Comment: Thank you, Naren Murali. I'll give it a try and will post the result tomorrow because I'm not at the office anymore. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the following solution in the app.js:

```
   cache: false,                            <-- here
   templateUrl : 'myHtml.html'
```

I mean I declared the outlined expression before templateUrl.